# Need to check and alert duplicate value in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can see the array in console but can not check them if there are same values in it.

```
   $('.tab2field').each(function () {
     PackageName.push($('.span2', this).val() );
     PackageCount.push($('.ex > :selected', this).text())
});
```

This is what i am trying to do.

```
   for (var i = 0; i <PackageName.length; i++) {
  if (PackageName[i] != current) {
      if (cnt > 0) {

      }
      current = PackageName;
      cnt = 1;
  } else {
      cnt++;
  }
  }
  if (cnt > 1) {
     alert(' Check multiple inputs');
  }
```

Comment: What have you done to check the values in Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do checking before pushing:

```
$('.tab2field').each(function () {
    var name = $('.span2', this).val();
    if (PackageName.indexOf(name) === -1) {
        PackageName.push(name);
        PackageCount.push($('.ex > :selected', this).text())
    } else {
        console.warn('Package ' + name + ' is already included');
    }
});
```

But I am not sure whether this is what you wanted to achieve becuase your question is a bit unclear